# SimpleCaptcha and wav playback

Tags: java, flash, captcha, html5-audio, jplayer

Our client is using [SimpleCaptcha](http://simplecaptcha.sourceforge.net/). My understanding is that SimpleCaptcha is able to produce audio captchas in WAVE format (.wav). Later these CAPTCHA-s are played back using the HTML5 audio tag, something like this:

```
<audio controls="controls" autoplay>
    <source src="captcha.wav" />
</audio>
```

Of course this is not cross browser compatible and one of the reasons is the WAVE format. This [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_audio.asp) suggests that IE9 supports only MP3 while most other browsers are fine with OGG and WAVE. Further MP3 is a patented to... to Fraunhofer?

Note: our back-end is Java based.

My question is what is the best fallback that we may offer to clients that do not support either the WAVE format (e.g. IE9) or the HTML5 audio tag at all? Due to patent issues I guess that dynamic conversion to mp3 on server side is not an option. Further I do not know any java library that may do this... I have seen nice solutions like [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/) but they say that "For cross-browser support, a format must be supplied that works in both HTML5 and Flash.", i.e. mp3, mp4. I didn't find any reliable flash based WAVE players too.

Comment: Did you solve this issue ? i am also facing the same problem

Comment: Yes - a quite stupid resolution was delivered at the end of the day :-( The unfortunate user is offered a download link if there is no play support detected. The client preferred this instead of any flash gadgets.

Comment: Oh wow.. we are planning to use flash rather ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help from others in the community, I have created a Flash button that can stream WAV files from the server to the client.  It is distributed with Securimage PHP Captcha for streaming audio CAPTCHAs to the client.

You could simply take this Flash button, or download and modify the Flash [source code](https://github.com/dapphp/securimage/tree/securimage_flash) to create your own custom one based on the same code.

You could use it as a fallback for when HTML5 audio isn't available.

Example usage would be:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
        data="securimage_play.swf?audio_file=/PATH/TO/AUDIO.wav"
        width="32" height="32">
    <param name="movie" value="securimage_play.swf?audio_file=/PATH/TO/AUDIO.wav" />
</object>
```

You can pass these additional options to `securimage_play.swf`:

- `bgcol`: background-color of the Flash button
- `icon_file`: URL to a png image to display as the icon on the Flash button

On a side note, I do find Microsoft's decision to not support WAV audio in the `<audio>` tag strange, especially since they pioneered WAV format with IBM.  Yes WAV files are bigger than the other compressed audio formats they support, but bandwidth is also increasing to the point where it doesn't matter.

Hope that helps.  Let me know if you try to implement it and have any questions.  You can see a demo of the audio streaming [here](http://phpcaptcha.org/try-securimage).

Comment: A great piece of work, thank you. May you please just hint why 16000Hz sample rate is not supported? It turns out that SimpleCaptcha generates wavs at exactly such a rate?

Comment: Ah that's too bad, I didn't know it didn't support it.  I looked at the code for the 3rd party library that we used for getting Flash to play WAV files and it appears it only supports 5512Hz, 11025Hz, 22050Hz, and 44100Hz.  I see there is also no way to change SimpleCaptcha to produce a WAV with a different sample rate.  The code for the sample rates in Flash is [here](https://github.com/dapphp/securimage/blob/securimage_flash/PopForge/de/popforge/audio/output/SoundFactory.as#L172),  I'll see what it takes to fix it but I don't have a copy of Flash at the moment.  That's too bad for the moment

Comment: Perhaps SimpleCaptcha can be easily modified to to work at 11025Hz but I have to recompile it :-). I'll try that today. I have no idea what it will take on the Flash side.

Comment: Yeah It may be a simple division by the correct value on the Flash side, or it may be more complicated.  I saw in the Java code it has the 16Hz hardcoded and says that is the only bitrate it supports, but maybe changing that value and recompiling is all it takes.

Comment: Hah, it is not that simple, if you do that the resulting audio is veeeery sloooow :-) Anyway it is not impossible. I think that your button is a solution to the SimpleCaptcha problem.

Comment: Bummer didn't think it'd be that easy.  I think someone at work has Flash, if I get a chance today I'll jump on their machine and try a couple things with the Flash version and see what it takes to get it to decode 16Hz.

Answer (score 2):

I think the help of @drew010 with their button was awesome!! Thank you.

To solve the same problem with rate frequency support between SimpleCaptcha (16000Hz) and supported audio for flash player (11025Hz) I've used an alternative solution instead change simplecaptcha source or try solve it at flash programming.

My captcha implementation has a custom audio captcha servlet (as supported by simplecaptcha), so I used the tip provided by @Claude in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276027/converting-the-sample-rate-on-the-fly-when-reading-a-wav-file-into-a-samples-arr) using [tritonus](http://www.tritonus.org/) lib to convert audio sample rate. The piece of code looks like that:

```
    AudioFormat outDataFormat = new AudioFormat((float) 11025.0, (int) 16, (int) 1, true, false);
    AudioInputStream lowResAIS = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(outDataFormat, audioCapthca.getChallenge().getAudioInputStream());
```

My captcha servlet code below:

```
public class AudioCaptchaServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        Map<Integer, String[]> voicesMap = new HashMap<Integer, String[]>();
        String[] fileLocs0 = {"/captcha/pt_BR/0.wav"};
        String[] fileLocs9 = {"/captcha/pt_BR/1.wav"};
        (...)

        voicesMap.put(0, fileLocs0);
        voicesMap.put(1, fileLocs1);
        (...)

        VoiceProducer voiceProducer = new RandomNumberVoiceProducer(voicesMap);

        AudioCaptcha ac = new AudioCaptcha.Builder()
            .addAnswer()
            .addNoise()
            .addVoice(voiceProducer)
            .build();

        req.getSession().setAttribute(AudioCaptcha.NAME, ac.getAnswer());

        //Converte Sons com bitrate de 16000Hz (simplecaptcha) para 11025Hz (suportada pelo flash player)
        AudioFormat outDataFormat = new AudioFormat((float) 11025.0, (int) 16, (int) 1, true, false);
        AudioInputStream lowResAIS = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(outDataFormat, ac.getChallenge().getAudioInputStream());

        CaptchaServletUtil.writeAudio(resp, new Sample(lowResAIS));
    }

    @Override protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(req, resp);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not working in my case... I get below exception                                      java.io.IOException: stream length not specified
 at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFileWriter.write(WaveFileWriter.java:121)
 at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.write(AudioSystem.java:1314)
 at uadmin.captcha.CaptchaServletUtil.writeAudio(CaptchaServletUtil.java:23)
 at demo.captcha.AudioCaptchaServlet.doGet(AudioCaptchaServlet.java:27)

Answer (score 0):

If any one still looking for It. Here is my code. It worked in all browsers for me.

```
<audio controls id="audioCaptcha">
    <source src="audio.wav" type='audio/wav' height="50px" width="100px"/>
    <embed src="audio.wav" type='audio/wav' autoplay="false" height="50px" width="100px"/>
</audio>
```