# simple captcha audio not working in IE

Tags: java

I am using simplecaptcha and its audio sound is not working in IE browser as it is of .wav formatt.

```
AudioCaptcha audioCap = new AudioCaptcha.Builder()
                .addAnswer(new TextProd((String) 
                .addNoise()
                .build();

CaptchaServletUtil.writeAudio(response, audioCap.getChallenge());
```

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758462/simplecaptcha-and-wav-playback